# Is there any better way to access patch and turtle 's variables at each tick?

Tags: netlogo, multi-agent

I need to update each turtle's wealth variable at each tick which by number of calls is on top of my profiler list.

I am sure the most computation time goes to calculating how many other agents are using same patch for their home and calculating the share for each turtle. food_carrying and my-home are turtle's properties and Storage is patch property.

```
to update-wealth
  let h my-home
  set wealth ([Storage] of my-home / (Count agents with [my-home = h]))  + food_carrying
end
```

Can you think of any better way to do it ?

```
Name                               Calls Incl T(ms) Excl T(ms) Excl/calls
UPDATE-WEALTH                    9744912 831703.608 461086.654      0.047
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be much faster to do this by patch rather than by turtle, since each turtle on a patch seems to be calculating the same value of wealth.  Perhaps something like:

```
ask patches [
  let my-turtles turtles-here
  if any? my-turtles [
    let w Storage / count my-turtles
    ask my-turtles [set wealth w + food_carrying]
    ]
  ]
]
```

If you kept a running set of patches with turtle homes you could just ask that subset and not have to worry about there not being any on the patch and getting a division by zero.

Comment: Each turtle calculates an equal share plus an individual wealth, but I agree with you I was not sure if its worth it to change the whole model to show my-home for patches not for turtles , however I am going to assign that variable to patch :)

Comment: let my-turtles turtles-here does not work for my model since its the family relationship which defines who lives in each patch , not their location :) but its ok I know how to do that :)